# In The Endless, what is the significance of the brewer's hut?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-endless

In the movie *The Endless*, the character Tim is the 'brewer' of the commune. When the protagonist, Justin and Aaron, eyes Tim's padlocked hut and asked what is in there, Tim shortly replied that it contains 'brewing equipment' without further explanation.

Nearing the conclusion of the movie and close to the Accession, we can see Tim opened the hut padlock and just left like he didnt care anymore.

What was in that hut? What's the significance of that hut and Tim's action leaving it open?